# count number of observations in a group

Tags: sas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
ID status 
101 Checked
101 Checked
101 NotChecked
101 Checked
101 NotChecked
```

I want to count the number of obs base don the status variable  like

```
ID status        Count
101 Checked       2
101 Checked       2 
101 NotChecked    1
101 Checked       1
101 NotChecked    1
```

I dont want to use proc sql because when I say group by then it sorts the dataset and gives the result where as here the Status variable is not sorted.

Comment: Why is the 3rd record there a 1 not a 2?

Comment: @Reeza the idea is to count the consecutive recoords with same Status, the third record is **NotChecked** and fourth is again **Checked** , as it appears only once it is counted as one

Answer (score 1):

Aggregating by groups will always require sorting unless you want to use some complex data step logic.

If you have a particular sort order that you want to keep, the easiest way is to create a key column that holds your desired order. You can then resort it back to the way you'd like it after grouping.

```
data have2;
    set have;
    varorder = _N_;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
        select id, status, count(*) as count
        from have2
        group by id, status
        order by varorder
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, a bit of a longer solution but basically add row and group identifiers to control the count. The `NOTSORTED` option on the BY statement helps to identify your groups uniquely.

```
data have;
input ID status $12.;
cards;
101 Checked
101 Checked
101 NotChecked
101 Checked
101 NotChecked
;;;;
run;

data grouped;
set have;
by id status notsorted;
retain MyGroups count;
if first.id then count=1;
else count+1;
if first.status then MyGroups+1;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select *, count(*) as numberFound
from grouped
group by MyGroups
order by ID, count;
quit;
```